# Do I need to manually define onChange handlers to populate state variables?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have a form with many input controls, which should be bound to respective state vars. Do I really need to define manual `onChange=..` handlers for each one so that, when I click Submit or press Enter, my state vars are populated?

e.g.

```
const [lastLoginDate, setLastLoginDate] = useState();
const [confirmed, setConfirmed] = useState(false);
..
<input type="text" value={lastLoginDate} onChange={this.handleLastLoginDate} ></input>
<input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={confirmed} onChange={this.handleConfirmed}></input>
...
// onChange handlers to populate state vars from input controls
handleLastLoginDate = (e) => {
    setLastLoginDate(e.target.value);
};
handleConfirmed = (e) => {
    setConfirmed(e.target.checked ? true : false);
};
...
// On Submit or Enter, I expect all State vars to contain populated values
```

This seems too laborious for me. I wish there was a way to simply specify

```
<input type="text" stateVar={lastLoginDate} ></input>
```

Is there a way to simplify state binding in React?

Comment: No, you don't; it's a common pattern to have a higher-order handler you pass the control name to, or even get it from the event's target. Read the docs, for example: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs

Comment: Not unless you use a form library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without adding more abstractions, it is necessary to use event handlers like `onChange` to call a function that updates your state. If you want a more compact syntax you can use anonymous arrow functions like this (note that this is not great when there is more than one line necessary in the handler):

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={lastLoginDate}
  onChange={(e) => setLastLoginDate(e.target.value)}
></input>
```